# Delete date that falls outside of inputted month

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a sub that formats a new time sheet. I need it to delete dates that fall outside of the inputted month (in this case, June, 2020). The code autofills the next 30 days after the first day, which covers the maximum days in a month (31 days), but also adds date for the first day(s) in the next month if the inputted month has less than 31 days. Here is my code:

```
Sub Calendar_Genorator3()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim MyInput As Variant
Dim StartDay As Variant
Dim DayofWeek As Variant
Dim CurYear As Variant
Dim CurMonth As Variant
Dim FinalDay As Variant
Dim Cell As Range
Dim RowCell As Long
Dim ColCell As Long
Dim Day1 As Range

Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
WS.Range("A1:R100").Clear

MyInput = InputBox("Type in Month and year for Calendar ")
    If MyInput = "" Then Exit Sub
       ' Get the date value of the beginning of inputted month.
       StartDay = DateValue(MyInput)
       ' Check if valid date but not the first of the month
       ' -- if so, reset StartDay to first day of month.
       If Day(StartDay) <> 1 Then
           StartDay = DateValue(Month(StartDay) & "/1/" & _
               Year(StartDay))
       End If

       'Set headers
       Range("a1").Value = Application.Text(MyInput, "mmmm") & " Time Sheet"
       Range("a2") = "Day"
       Range("c2") = "Time In"
       Range("d2") = "Time Out"
       Range("e2") = "Hours"
       Range("f2") = "Notes"
       Range("g2") = "Overtime"

       'Set weekdays
       Range("a3") = "Sunday"
       Range("a4") = "Monday"
       Range("a5") = "Tuesday"
       Range("a6") = "Wednesday"
       Range("a7") = "Thursday"
       Range("a8") = "Friday"
       Range("a9") = "Saturday"

       DayofWeek = Weekday(StartDay)
       ' Set variables to identify the year and month as separate variables.
       CurYear = Year(StartDay)
       CurMonth = Month(StartDay)
       ' Set variable and calculate the first day of the next month.
       FinalDay = DateSerial(CurYear, CurMonth + 1, 1)
       ' Place a "1" in cell position of the first day of the chosen month based on DayofWeek.
       Select Case DayofWeek
           Case 1
               Range("b3").Value = 1
           Case 2
               Range("b4").Value = 1
           Case 3
               Range("b5").Value = 1
           Case 4
               Range("b6").Value = 1
           Case 5
               Range("b7").Value = 1
           Case 6
               Range("b8").Value = 1
           Case 7
               Range("b9").Value = 1
       End Select

'Loop through range b3:b44 incrementing each cell after the "1" cell.
For Each Cell In Range("b3:b44")
    RowCell = Cell.Row
    ColCell = Cell.Column
    'Do if "1" is in column B or 2.
        If Cell.Row = 1 And Cell.Column = 2 Then
        ' Do if current cell is not in 1st column.
            ElseIf Cell.Row <> 1 Then
                If Cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value >= 1 Then
                    Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
                    ' Stop when the last day of the month has been entered.
                    If Cell.Value > (FinalDay - StartDay) Then
                        Cell.Value = ""
                        ' Exit loop when calendar has correct number of days shown.
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
        End If
Next

For Each Cell In Range("b3:b9")
    If Cell.Value = "" Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Clear
    End If
Next
'Clears rows without dates

For Each Cell In Range("b3:b9")
    If Cell.Value = "" Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
'Deletes top rows without dates; needs a loop to successfully delete all empty rows

    Range("b2") = "Date"
    'Added "Date" in later so date insert works

Set Day1 = WS.Cells.Find(What:="1", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
        'Find start day, which is day 1
        If Not Day1 Is Nothing Then
            Day1.Value = Application.Text(MyInput, "mmm-d")
        End If

        With Day1
            Day1.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B3:B33"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End With

'These final lines of code don't delete ranges with dates that fall outside of the inputted month, because FinalDay doesn't refer to the last day of the month. I need to come up with something that refers to the last day of the month. 
        FinalDay.Select
        With Selection
                Cell.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
End Sub
```

Here's the output of this code. Any ideas on how to delete the rows that have dates that fall outside of the inputted month? I'm also open to writing this sub an entirely different way; I did it this way because I'm basing it on MS template code.

[image]

Comment: Your code fails for me on the line `Day1.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B3:B33"), Type:=xlFillDefault` regardless of what I type into the input. Instead of deleting what you previously put in, why don't you just NOT put it in? End the loop on the last day of the month.  -- BTW, what I've seen so far, this VBA can be totally replaced by a few Excel worksheet formulas.

Comment: @tylyn There's a reason I want to format the dates as #/##/#### instead of just having the integers in the cell. I want to use the dates in column B to insert the day of the week in column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is a very nice effort. With the code below I have taken a different approach. I hope you will like to study it. I've added lots of comments.

```
Sub Calendar_Generator()
    ' 046

    Dim Ws          As Worksheet
    Dim MyInput     As String               ' InputBox generates a string
    Dim StartDay    As Date                 ' this must be date
    Dim Sp()        As String               ' working array
    Dim i           As Integer              ' looping index
    Dim R           As Long                 ' row counter

    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet     ' not a good idea. Always specify the tab by name!
    Ws.Range("A1:R100").Clear

    Do
        MyInput = InputBox("Enter the start date for the Calendar:")
        If MyInput = "" Then Exit Sub
    Loop While Not IsDate(MyInput)          ' repeat if entry isn't recognized as a date

    ' Set the date value of the beginning of inputted month.
    ' -- regardless of the day the user entered, even if missing
    StartDay = DateSerial(Year(CDate(MyInput)), Month(CDate(MyInput)), 1)

    'Set headers
    Range("a1").Value = Format(StartDay, "mmmm") & " Time Sheet"
    Sp = Split("Day,Date,Time In,Time Out,Hours,Notes,Overtime", ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
        Ws.Cells(2, 1 + i).Value = Sp(i)     ' always specify the worksheet
    Next i

    ' fill the days for the selected month
    ' == the last day of a month is always the day before the first of the next
    '    here deducting 2 to count from 0
    For R = 0 To Day(DateAdd("m", 1, StartDay) - 2)
        With Ws.Cells(3 + R, 2)
            .Value = StartDay + R
            .NumberFormat = "d-mmm"
            .Offset(, -1).Value = StartDay + R
            .Offset(, -1).NumberFormat = "dddd"
        End With
    Next R
End Sub
```

If you look at the declarations, four out of six - two thirds of their total - are used for code management. That shows where my focus was, and the result is shorter, more efficient code. Much of this was achieved by following a simple rule (which the macro recorder doesn't seem to know): Use cell addressing syntax for addressing cells and range addressing syntax only for addressing ranges of cells. Cell coordinates are easy to calculate and use in loops.

Comment: This worked like a charm! The split function and using loops for cells is new to me- I'll play with them and figure out how they work- thank you Variatus!!